# tracking canvas x and y coordinates animation on mousemove event

Tags: javascript, canvas, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a circle moving animation with `mousemove` event, each time the circle will moving from my `mouse.x` and `mouse.y`coordinates on the screen. so I declare my `mouse` coordinates object and `drawCricle`object constructor:

```
    var mouse = {
        x:canvas.width/2,
        y:canvas.height/2
    }


        function Circle (x,y,r,dy){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.update = function(){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
            ctx.fill();

            this.y+=this.dy;

            if(this.y<this.r || this.y+this.r>canvas.height){
                this.dy=-this.dy;
            }
        }
    }
```

and after i add the `mousemove`event so i am thinking i can assign the mouse x/y coordinate through my `mouvemove eventListenter`:

```
    var myCircle = new Circle(mouse.x,mouse.y,30,2);

    function animate(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        myCircle.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
        mouse.x = e.clientX;
        mouse.y = e.clientY;
        animate();
    });
```

the problem is the `mouse.x`and`mouse.y`value won't change from the original `canvas.width/2`value, so i have tried to wrapper my `animation()`function inside the `window.addEventListener` instead just calling it within, just like:

```
    window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
        mouse.x = e.clientX;
        mouse.y = e.clientY;
        var myCircle = new Circle(mouse.x,mouse.y,30,2);

        function animate(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        myCircle.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
animate();
    });
```

this could work a bit but it looks really stupid and makes my browser comes huge laggy spikes, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would also need to pass the mouse coordinates when calling the `update` function ...

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mouse = {
   x: canvas.width / 2,
   y: canvas.height / 2
};

function Circle(x, y, r, dy) {
   this.r = r;
   this.dy = dy;
   this.update = function(x, y) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.fill();
      this.y += this.dy;
      if (this.y < this.r || this.y + this.r > canvas.height) {
         this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
   };
}

var myCircle = new Circle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 30, 2);

function animate() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   myCircle.update(mouse.x, mouse.y);
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
   mouse.x = e.offsetX;
   mouse.y = e.offsetY;
});

animate();
```

```css
body{margin:10px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden}canvas{border:1px solid #e4e6e8}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="635" height="208"></canvas>
```

Comment: should i add this.update = function(this.x,this.y) {} inside my circle object? or there is no difference to declare the x and y properties within the circle constructor?

Comment: No, that won't work, as you create a circle object only once but the update function is getting called multiple times, hence you need to pass those coords explicitly. In this particular case there is no diff. between declaring those within the constructor and use it directly.